# Cloudwatch Logs Subscription to Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have subscribed cloudwatch log group to kinesis data stream. The kinesis data stream has 2 shards. A lambda function is a consumer of the kinesis stream. I keep pushing logs to the cloudwatch log group. In the lambda event I see irregular number of data records from kinesis. The number varies from 1 to 17K.

Question 1: On what basis are the batches sent from cloudwatch to kinesis to lambda?

At times there are WriteProvisionedThrouhputExceeded exceptions. Assume the logs are throttled and not sent to kinesis.

Question 2: If so, will the cloudwatch retry sending those messages to kinesis on its own or not? In that case what should be done?